# trouble with single and double quotations within a php function to output html & php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables

I am trying use a hook in wordpress theme to swap out footer credits on a website using a function.

As you can see the "$my_content" variable output includes php as well as html.

This string outputs as expected when used seperatly outside this particular function, so I can only deduce that the problem is caused by the added single quotation marks required by the my_content variable to output the result?

```
 function et_get_footer_credits()
{
  $my_content = '<p id="footer-info">&copy; Copyright <?php echo showDateRange('2010'); ?> <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">Company name</a>text</p>';
  return $my_content;
}
```

Comment: what function it is? js or php? for php you need to use concatination something like $my_content = '<p id="footer-info">&copy; Copyright'.showDateRange('2010').'<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">Company name</a>text</p>';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RohitS comments says, you need to concenate `$my_content`

```
$my_content = '<p id="footer-info">&copy; Copyright ' . showDateRange('2010').' <a href="'. esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) .'">Company name</a>text</p>';
```

To echo the return of the `et_get_footer_credits` function,

```
echo et_get_footer_credits();
```

Comment: thanks, that was my original solution, and I couldn't get it to work, but that does do th etrick too, so thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use php in string. You should change your function, so the html part will be separate from `$my_content` variable. You can use [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_get_clean](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.ob-get-clean.php) function. Example:

```
function et_get_footer_credits() {
    ob_start();
    ?>

    <p id="footer-info">
        &copy; Copyright <?php echo showDateRange('2010'); ?> 
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">Company name</a>
        text
    </p>

    <?php
    $my_content = ob_get_clean();

    return $my_content;
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks for that, works first time...thanks for your response, appreciate it